# Element transform scale maintained after transform rotation occurrs

Tags: javascript

I have an element I am zooming in (one button) and then rotating (another button)

When I zoom in on the element the scale gets updated, then when I go to rotate element the scale is not kept from the zoom (but it really is, I can see the value is maintained browser debug) but it zooms back out to the initial scale when rotate is clicked.

```js
let spin = 0;
let zoom = 1;

$('#SpinRight').click(function(){

  //I know for a fact scale keeps value here, but zooms back out to original size when I     //click spin
  
  spin += 25;
  $('#element').css({'transform' : 'rotate(' + spin + 'deg'});
})

$('#Magnify').click(function(){
  zoom += 0.1;
  $('#element').css({'transform' : 'scale(' + zoom + ')'});
})
```

Comment: `transform` has only a single value, you've to combine all the transform function calls into a single string, or use [matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix()).

Comment: can you give me an example of this with current logic?

Comment: I'm sure you can concatenate a string without an example, you've already multiple string concatenations in your code.

Comment: is there a comma between `rotate(value)` and `scale(value1)`?

Comment: No, you can see that in ray's answer, or read from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) ...

Comment: or is just white space used to concat them?

Comment: word. I got it. thanks fellas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transform` rules don't stack, so if you do:

```css
transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: scale(0.5);
```

The `scale` transform *replaces* the `rotate` rule, it doesn't add to it. If you want both you need to specify them both in a single rule:

```css
transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.5);
```

You could keep track of the rotation and scale in css properties and then have a rule that applies them both. (Or just apply them the way you're already doing it, but do both for each update.)

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
let rotate = 0;
let scale = 1;

document.querySelector('.rotate').addEventListener('click', () => {
  demo.style.setProperty('--rotate', `${rotate += 10}deg`);
});

document.querySelector('.scale').addEventListener('click', () => {
  demo.style.setProperty('--scale', scale += 0.1);
});
```

```css
.demo {
  --rotate: 0;
  background: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotate, 0)) scale(var(--scale, 1));
}

button {
  position: relative; /* just so the buttons stay on top */
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>

<button class="rotate">Rotate</button>
<button class="scale">Scale</button>
```

Comment: is this logic able to be performed in-line with javascript like my post?